# Rails passing more than one parameters

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Respected ppl ...

I have a grave design issue since many days ...kindly help out ...

[image]

Im coming to this stage from the previous screen after entering the hospital_id which u can c from the URL is 10 (using ransack) ... at this stage when i click "Add performance detail for employee" im passing only the employee_id to the performance creation screen ...

[image]

How do i capture the hospital_id from the previous screen and store in my performance creation screen ? ... (it has field hospital_id) ....

can i somehow use this raw sql query to store hospital_id directly ? ...

SELECT hospital_id
FROM  `employee_sanction_working` 
WHERE  `employee_id`

Pls do help ...

Thnx

Comment: You can pass hospital_id as a parameter. /new?id=3007&hospital_id=10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways you can resolve your problem:

1) you can pass hospital_id in parameter as Rubyman and Santhosh K have suggested Or

2) you can create a class variable in controller which you can use in your erb or haml view.

for example:

```
in controller:

def new 
    @hospital_id = params[:hospital_id] #this you can use in your view
end
in view
Hospital ID is <%= @hospital_id %>
```

Please refer [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html) for more information

Comment: Who has given downvote ? Please leave a comment of what you have think of so that I can also know what is the mistake.

Comment: Thnx very much :) ... this gave me a clue and served the purpose ...

    <%= link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")),
            new_performaone_url(:id => empsancwork.employee_id, :hospital_id => empsancwork.hospital_id),
            :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-success',:id => 'addnew' %>

=============================================================== 
def new
    @performaone = Performaone.new(:employee_id => params[:id], :hospital_id => params[:hospital_id])
 end

Comment: Can anybody please remove this downvote ? or tell whats wrong I have written in the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the hospital_id as parameter to "Add performance detail for employee" link.

Comment: How do i pass 2 parameters simultaneously ... currently im passing only employee_id ...

Im new to this ... pls do tell where to make appropriate changes....

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to